# ASP.NET : EF 5.X : LINQ - Using Rules in ASPxGridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to achieve adding conditions into a table where, for example, if the column `cleared amount` is not equal to the column `total amount` is displays red text.

I have been researching and came across a perfect example of what I want done which is  [here](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Rows/ConditionalFormatting.aspx)  - by DevExpress.

I took a look at the ASP section of the code but it did not work (I received no errors but the code did not actually do anything so I am thinking that there must be a way to do it in the design section).

An example of what I want to achieve:

[image]

But of-course, in the ASPxGridView and not Excel - this is just an example of the rule principle I am trying to achieve.

Edit: I have browsed the design of the ASPxGridView and have not found where you can add these rules like [DevExpress](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/Rows/ConditionalFormatting.aspx) say you can on the link provided at the top. I have only found the Conditional Formatting that allows you to add icons but **without** a dependency/rule.

Edit: I have come across [Formatting](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridView_FormatConditionstopic) but again, there is no code or reference on where to start on the adding rules to the formatted cells within the GridView. I'm not sure if this link is relevant to what I am trying to achieve but it may help people understand more.

The examples provided on the DevExpress site are only written as direct ASP code rather than back-end code. When you import the Entity Data Module to the GridView, this code is automatically done for you so the references on the site are not actually relevant however, I have tried to add:

```
 <dx:GridViewFormatConditionTopBottom FieldName="TotalAmount" Rule="AboveAverage" Format="RedText" />
```

To the Column I am trying to add the rule to (not the rule I am looking for but just to see the output) and nothing changed even with 523 pages of data in the GridView.

Thank-you in advance.

**Edit to thoughts - Front end:**

```
<dx:GridViewFormatConditionTopBottom FieldName="TotalAmount" Rule="AboveAverage" Format="RedText" />
```

**Back-end:**

```
public class GridViewFormatConditionColorScale : GridFormatConditionColorScale {
    if( rule == "....." ) { }
}
```

But this is not actual code because I am just guessing to help people understand the methods.

Edit: Another image to show that DevExpress is wrong about having rules inside the Conditional Formatting of the GridxView.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what are You looking for. Maybe computed property is all Youy need. Ex.: class Entity1 { int TotalOfSomething { get { return RelationToSomething.Sum(); } }

Comment: The link I gave in the Question is what I am trying to achieve, but the site does not explain how to achieve what they have done: therefore, I am wondering if anyone else has come across wanting to do this and can help me out. @ŁukaszJankowski